# JQuery Sortable handle with span not support in ie 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-sortable

my code is perfectly working in firefox chrome safari opera but sort with span not working in ie 9 here is my code

```
$(function() {
    var lastRow = $("#<%=divChapters.ClientID%> tr:last").children("td:first").html();
                  $('#<%=divChapters.ClientID%> tbody').sortable({ opacity: 0.6,cursor: "move",handle: "span", update: function() {
                   var tableTdId = [];
                            $("table tbody tr:visible td:first-child").each(function(){
                                tableTdId.push($.trim($(this).text()));
                            });
                       var tableTdId = tableTdId.join(',');
                       var order = $('#<%=divChapters.ClientID%> tbody').sortable("serialize"); 
                       var App_Id = $("#<%= hfAppId.ClientID %>").val();
                       BlockUI();
                       CallServerMethod(tableTdId + "^" + lastRow + "^" +  App_Id +"_UpdateChapterOrder", "");                                                   
                  }                               
});


<td class="chapterDeletetd"> <div style="text-align: right; padding-right: 13px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left:32px;"> <span class="spanSortable">Drag drop chapter to change order <img class="spanSortableImage" src="../Images/cursor.png"> </span> </div></td>
```

Comment: Please give more information about the problem in your questions. 'It doesn't work' is not enough information. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: code is perfectly working when i am not add handle: "span", now code not work and console not show any error

Comment: is there any span element in your code if yes then where it is exactly, my guess would be in <td> right? Can you pass some html code you have used

Comment: <td class="chapterDeletetd">
<div style="text-align: right; padding-right: 13px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-left:32px;">
<span class="spanSortable">Drag drop chapter to change order
<img class="spanSortableImage" src="../Images/cursor.png">
</span>
</div></td>

Answer (score 1):

This error occured when we use jquery_v1.7.2.js and jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js
To solve this problem use latest version of jquery .js files

jquery-1.8.3.js

jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js

jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js